# Why math equation creates error in document?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, mathtools

In my latex document as long as I use this formula, it throws tons of unrelated errors which is working without the formula. Although it is creating a formula on the document, but the problem is, numbering of formula the is not aligned the formula, but one return down and when I refer it with \eqref{charging_gp} for example, it is showing section(i.g. 2.2.1) number instead of math formula number (i.g. 2.1). Also, it is missing with my bibliography (some of are showing, some not). Could anybody help me to detect the error please, because I see none?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation} \label{charging_gp}


     i_{c,gp}=min(0.7C,\frac{4.2-{v_{0}}}{r_{r}}+\beta*\frac{4.2-{\widetilde{v_{0}}}}{r_{r}}).



\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome! Blank lines are not allowed inside math displays.

Comment: @egreg OMG, thank you so much, it was so simple.

Comment: If you want an almost blank line, you can just use a single `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) just said ("Blank lines are not allowed inside math displays."), you should write:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:nice}
i_{c,gp}= \min(0.7C,\frac{4.2-{v_{0}}}{r_{r}}+\beta*\frac{4.2-{\tilde{v}_{0}}}{r_{r}}).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You should also write `\min` instead of `min`. Also `\tilde[v}_[0}` seems nicer than `\widetilde[v_[0}}`

Comment: @ Denis, thanks for the imrovement.

Comment: You forgot on equation label ...

Comment: @Zarko Right, thanks..

Comment: You may also want to suggest replacing `\widetilde{v_{0}}` with `\tilde{v}_0`; either replacing the `*` symbol after `\beta` with `\cdot` or (better still) omitting it entirely; and enlarging the parentheses.

Comment: @Zarko Right again. There are many ugly things in the OP's equation. I did not want to correct them all.